# Improving efficiency of data.table grouped operations

Tags: r, performance, data.table

I need to make a comparison between all possible row combinations in a data frame. Despite using [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) group operations with an efficient function, the operation takes a very long time when the number of row combinations is high (e.g., hundreds of thousands, or more).

Here is an example dataset:

```
set.seed(23)
my_df <- matrix(data = rnorm(6000, mean = 100, sd = 10), nrow = 200, ncol = 30)
my_df <- data.table::data.table(as.data.frame(my_df))
```

I start by creating a dataframe of all the possible row combinations. Then I use [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) to perform group operations using `.SD`.

```
# create dataframe of all row combinations
plot_combs <- data.table::data.table(t(combn(seq(nrow(my_df)), 2)))

# create grouped operations function
.PLOT_COMP <- function(x){
  .sd_my_df <- my_df[as.numeric(i),]
  outer(t(as.matrix(.sd_my_df[1, ])), t(as.matrix(.sd_my_df[2, ])), pmin) * 2
}
# run and record system time for grouped operation
system.time(plot_combs[, .PLOT_COMP(.SD), by = seq(nrow(plot_combs))][,-1])
```

Despite the function itself, `.PLOT_COMP` taking ~0 seconds to complete for each group, the whole operation is slow. I am hoping to improve efficiency considerably.

Any ideas on how to improve the efficiency of this operations? Thank you.

UPDATE------------

Improvements based on Gregor Thomas' recommendations -

```
my_df <- t(matrix(data = rnorm(6000, mean = 100, sd = 10), nrow = 200, ncol = 30))
plot_combs_m <- combn(seq(nrow(my_df)), 2)

system.time(for(i in seq(nrow(plot_combs_m))){
  
  my_plots <- plot_combs_m[,i]
  outer(my_df[,my_plots[1]], my_df[,my_plots[2]])
  
})
```

This code runs in 0.02 seconds instead of over a minute.

Comment: I mean, you're not really using `data.table` in this.  If your computations were being done *on a data.table object* then you'd be getting some speed-up from `data.table`. But you're really just using it to index the combinations.

Comment: The way your code is now, `.PLOT_COMP` is hard-coded to always use the 1st and 2nd row of `my_df`. The `x` argument is ignored. So you're repeating the exact same computation on the exact same input however many times.

Comment: Assuming you mean to have `.PLOT_COMP` select different rows from `my_df` based on the iteration tracked in the data.table, you could probably get a lot of speed-up by having `my_df` as a `matrix` rather than a `data.frame`. Converting a data frame row to a vector is much more expensive than converting a matrix row to a vector. Since matrices (and data frames) are stored in memory as columns you'd get a tiny bit more efficiency by transposing `my_df` first, and using columns instead of rows.

Comment: I'd also question whether you really need the `t(as.matrix())` at all. If you have 2 test vectors `a` and `b`, then `outer(t(as.matrix(a)), t(as.matrix(b)), pmin) * 2` has the same values as `outer(a, b, pmin) * 2`, but with a different shape. Do you really need the results in a `1 x n x 1 x n`-dimensional array? Seems like a `n x n` matrix could probably work... you could always combine the matrices into an array afterwards.

Comment: Overall, if you want run `.PLOT_COMP` a few hundred thousand times, as long as you don't make gross inefficiencies, it doesn't matter much whether you use a `for` loop, `mapply`, `data.table` or whatever else to manage the iteration. All that matters is that `.PLOT_COMP` is as fast as possible. [Profile your code](https://support.posit.co/hc/en-us/articles/218221837-Profiling-R-code-with-the-RStudio-IDE) to find what's slow about it, and use `bench::mark` to compare improvements.

Comment: Thank you. I updated my question to address several of your comments. Would parallelization be useful in situations like this? In what situations would you consider Rcpp?

Comment: 0.02 seconds seems pretty good. Parallelization could help, but you'd want to be careful about how you set it up. It takes overhead to set up the parallelization, distribute the tasks, and compile the results. Your individual iterations are tiny, and running, say, 1M tiny tasks in parallel will not get nearly as much speed us as running 10k medium tasks in parallel. Basically you want to make sure you're giving enough work to each parallel process at a time to make up for the extra overhead. It might work to batch your combinations into 128 groups, and try to run the groups in parallel.

Comment: Rcpp is most effective at speeding up an R code bottleneck. Especially if some of your tasks can't be vectorized, or if there is an early stopping condition you could impose, Rcpp will have huge gains. That's not the case here. Rcpp will still certainly be faster, but hard to say how much faster in a case like this where the R code is already pretty efficient.

Comment: (For clarity, `cpp11` is also effective at it. While I believe `Rcpp` has more documentation and examples, there are [other motivations](https://cpp11.r-lib.org/articles/motivations.html) for considering `cpp11` instead. They both require a level of "awareness" of C++ coding concepts, both provide some convenience mechanisms (to varying degrees), and both end up with potential significant speed-up at the expense of coding complexity.